# Change limits for a plot on a click in another plot in R

Tags: r, plot, shiny, hover

I need to have two plots displayed. The first plot is the main scatter plot. And the second plot must be changed each time one clicks a point in the first plot. So I need the behavior similar to the picture at https://davidgohel.github.io/ggiraph/index.html

To be more precise, each point of the first plot must be associated with the x-limits of the second plot.

I have found a corresponding example [How to display many points from plotly_click in R Shiny?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616790/how-to-display-many-points-from-plotly-click-in-r-shiny)
and modified it accordingly

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot1"),
  plotlyOutput("plot2")
)

range2=1000000
p1x=runif(10)
p1y=runif(10)
p1t=runif(10)*range2

times=seq(1,range2)
#ys=cumsum(rnorm(range2)/sqrt(range2))
ys=runif(range2)


plot2xlim=c(1000,2000)
p2 <- plot_ly()
p2 <- add_trace(p2, x = times, y = ys, type = "scattergl", mode = "lines",
                line = list(width = 1, color = "blue"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # make plotly plot
  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    g <- ggplot()+geom_point(aes(x=p1x,y=p1y))
    ggplotly(g)
  })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({
    selpoint <- event_data("plotly_click")$pointNumber[1]+1
    plot2xlim <- c(p1t[selpoint]-500,p1t[selpoint]+500)
    p2 <<- layout(p2, xaxis = list(range = plot2xlim), 
                  yaxis = list(range = c(0, 1)))
    p2
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However the code works very-very slowly, since `plot2` is built for a huge data. So it takes much time to rebuild it.

Is there a way not to redraw the second plot on each click, but just to change its x-limits?

Comment: your example gives `Error in "plotly"::"ggplotly": object 'p1t' not found`

Comment: @dww I have inserted a sample generated data into the example.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is no way to get around this, as every change/query in the graph implies a re-rendering of the graph, ever since Shiny sends new data to the second graph every time a data point is clicked on the first graph.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you asked, but...

We can build a plotly object with an x-axis slider in it. The redraw isn't instant but it's much faster than reloading in the subset of data afresh each time you want to change the range.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

range2=1000000
p1x=runif(10)
p1y=runif(10)
p1t=runif(10)*range2
times=seq(1,range2)
ys=runif(range2)

# Put the data in a data frame
data <- data.frame(x = times, y = ys)

# Use ggplotly to take a ggplot object and covert it to plotly
p2 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_line() 
ggplotly(p2) %>% rangeslider()
```